# Integral of matrix exponential: $\int_0^T e^{At}\: e^{A^{\top}t} \: \mathrm{d}t $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, matrices

Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, is there any way to derive a closed-form solution of:

$$\int_0^T e^{At}\:  e^{A^{\top}t} \: \mathrm{d}t $$

In general, $A$ and $ A^{\top}$ do not commute so $e^{At}\:  e^{A^{\top}t} \neq e^{(A+A^{\top})t}$.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, but here is one observation. If we want the limit as $T \to \infty$ (assuming this limit exists), i.e. the matrix
$$
M = \int_0^\infty e^{At} e^{A^\top t}dt,
$$
then one could note that $M$ is the solution to the [continuous time Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation)
$$
AM + MA^T = -I.
$$
With [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), this solution can be expressed as
$$
M = -\operatorname{vec}^{-1}[(I \otimes A + A \otimes I)^{-1}\operatorname{vec}(I)].
$$